# Finite Purely Inseparable Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, separable-extension

Let $F\subseteq E$ be purely inseparable with $|E:F|=n$. If  $\alpha\in E$ show that $\alpha ^n\in F$ ?

***HINT***

If $ α∉F $ show that  $|F[α]:F[α^p ]|=p$, where $\mathrm{char}(F)=p$.

We know that $α^{p^m }\in F$ for some integer $m≥0$....and we know that $n$ is a power of $p$, but how I can show that $p^m=n$?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using the hint? What can you say about $[F[\alpha]:F[\alpha^{p^k}]$?

Comment: I don't know how to use it if you can help

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $k\geqslant 1$ is such that $\alpha^{p^k}\not\in F$. Then you can apply your hint to each extension $F[\alpha^{p^i}]/F[\alpha^{p^{i+1}}]$ with $i<k$, which gives $[F[\alpha^{p^i}]:F[\alpha^{p^{i+1}}]]=p$, so by induction $[F[\alpha]:F[\alpha^{p^k}]]=p^k$.

You should be able to conclude from there.